# C# UnauthorizedAccessException when enabling MessageMode for read-only named pipe (NamedPipeClientStream class)

Tags: c#, .net, named-pipes

There's a problem with the `NamedPipeClientStream` class in .NET, in that you cannot create an instance of this class with `PipeDirection.In`, and then successfully change the `ReadMode` to `PipeTransmissionMode.Message`.

Attempting to do so will raise an `UnauthorizedAccessException`. Although pipes would usually be used to communicate between processes, this simple example within a single process shows the problem:

```
var pipeOut = new NamedPipeServerStream("SomeNamedPipe", 
                                        PipeDirection.Out, 
                                        1, 
                                        PipeTransmissionMode.Message);
var pipeIn = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", 
                                       "SomeNamedPipe", 
                                       PipeDirection.In);
pipeIn.Connect();
pipeIn.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;
```

This code will throw an `UnauthorizedAccessException` when attempting to set the ReadMode Property.

---

In a search for information on this problem, I found references to it in other places, such as here:

- [Named pipes issue: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.](http://adventuresindevelopment.blogspot.cl/2008/07/named-pipes-issue-systemunauthorizedacc.html)
- [WPF - Messaging using Windows Pipes protocol](http://www.shujaat.net/2011/01/wpf-messaging-using-windows-pipes.html)
- [PipeTransmissionMode.Message: How do .NET named pipes distinguish between messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28635708/3418322)

All of these posts mention that this is "weird", "odd", etc, but don't explain "why" it doesn't work, and all give the same workaround, that "for some strange reason" setting the pipe direction to `InOut` makes it work.

It's true that this does make it work, but it requires fundamentally changing the definition of the pipe, on both ends, to full duplex rather than going in a single direction, which I consider to be a very poor approach, and unless you're able to change both the client and the server, this may not even be possible.

---

My question was, why does enabling message mode on an inbound pipe cause an exception, and is there a better way to address this issue than changing the pipe to bi-directional mode?

Comment: It surely doesn't help that the `PipeDirection` enum is named exactly backwards.  You write to the input end of a unidirectional pipe, the data goes down the pipe to the other process, and then can be read from the output end.  But `PipeDirection.In` means readable (the output end of the pipe).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Looking at the Microsoft reference source, I could see that setting the `ReadMode` property simply calls the win32 `SetNamedPipeHandleState` function to perform the operation, with errors from this call raised as exceptions. As per the documentation [SetNamedPipeHandleState function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365787(v=vs.85).aspx) it states about the pipe handle that in order to call this function

> the handle must have GENERIC_WRITE access to the named pipe for a
>   write-only or read/write pipe, or it must have GENERIC_READ and
>   FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES access for a read-only pipe.

Herein lies the problem.

If we look at the constructors for NamedPipeClientStream that take in a `PipeDirection` setting, we see that they only request `GENERIC_READ` access for `PipeDirection.In`, and `GENERIC_WRITE` access for `PipeDirection.Out` (or both for `InOut`). This means that any pipe opened in `Out` or `InOut` mode will work, as `GENERIC_WRITE` access is sufficient for those cases, but we need both `GENERIC_READ` and `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` for a read-only pipe, which the `NamedPipeClientStream` class never requests. This is a defect in the class, and should be corrected by Microsoft.

I've submitted a bug report on Microsoft Connect here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1825187

Please up-vote it if you come across this problem yourself, it might help speed up a fix.

---

Until a fix (none as of 3/2017), one can work around this problem entirely by using a different constructor for `NamedPipeClientStream`.

There's one overload of the constructor that takes in, instead of a `PipeDirection` enumeration, a `PipeAccessRights` enumeration instead, where you can specify the particular combination of access rights you want to obtain for the handle. The constructor then derives the direction of the pipe from the combination of specified access rights (`In` if `ReadData` is specified, `Out`" if `WriteData` is specified, `InOut` if they are both specified).

This means, you can solve this problem without having to make your pipes full duplex, by simply changing a constructor line like this:

```
var pipeIn = new NamedPipeClientStream("<ServerName>", "<PipeName>", PipeDirection.In);
```

to this:

```
var pipeIn = 
   new NamedPipeClientStream("<ServerName>", 
                             "<PipeName>", 
                             PipeAccessRights.ReadData | PipeAccessRights.WriteAttributes, 
                             PipeOptions.None, 
                             System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.None, 
                             System.IO.HandleInheritability.None);
```

If you use this alternate constructor as a suggested workaround, the result will be identical and indistinguishable from the result you would get from the first form of the constructor, with the exception that this additional access right will be obtained, so that message mode can be enabled.

Comment: `Error CS1729 'NamedPipeServerStream' does not contain a constructor that takes 6 arguments`

Comment: @AlexG You need to make these changes on `NamedPipeClientStream` as shown. Your error indicates you were trying to modify `NamedPipeServerStream`.

Comment: Note - Microsoft Connect Has Been Retired. Look forward to link-jumping.

Comment: It's almost 2023 and bug is still not fixed. Sad emoji.

Comment: It gets worse. In .NET 6 the package that provided `PipeAccessRights` and the corresponding constructor are completely gone. What to do now?

Comment: @LOST [The docs say `enum PipeAccessRights` is present in .NET 6 and 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.pipeaccessrights?view=net-7.0) - though the Stream's ctor is gone, yes - perhaps you can still do it with `PipeAccessRule`?

Comment: @LOST crazy this is still an issue in 2023. Since .NET "Core" (.NET 5+) is now open source though, we can fit it ourselves. I've added a fix and opened a pull request under https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/94742. Hopefully it gets merged soon and this issue will be resolved for future versions.